# Replace value in shortcode with different value in html

Tags: php, attributes, shortcode

I have a shortcode for a CSS accordion. One of the attributes is $open for the checkbox's "checked" value. Right now, if they type open=checked, it will pass checked="checked" and that div will be visible by default. Is there anyway to replace a custom value with the actual html value? For instance, I want the user to be able to use "open=yes" and have it pass "checked=checked" in the HTML.

```
// TOGGLE BOXES
function sc_tog_boxes( $attr, $content = null ) {
    return '<ul class="togboxes">' . $content . '</ul>';
}
add_shortcode('togboxes', 'sc_tog_boxes');

function sc_tog_box( $atts , $content = null ) {

    // Attributes
    extract( shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'number' => '1',
            'heading' => 'you forgot the heading tag: heading="your heading"',
            'open' => '',
        ), $atts )
    );

    // Code
    return '<li><label for="' . $number . '">' . $heading . ' <span class="toggle-icon">[+/-]</span></label><input type="checkbox" name="a" id="' . $number . '" checked="' . $open . '"><div class="togbox">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</div></li>';
}
add_shortcode( 'togbox', 'sc_tog_box' );
```

UPDATE: Okay, I need to rephrase this because the presence of the "checked" attribute means "checked" without any parameter anyway. So I need to be able to add "checked" in the html if they just type "open" in the shortcode, but have no checked attribute if they don't type open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
if($open === 'yes'){
    $open = 'checked';
}
else {
    $open = '';
}
```